# Illegal instruction (core dumped) using Ubuntu VM + JUCE graphics library

Tags: c++, gcc, juce

Whenever I try to run a compiled program, using the JUCE graphics library, from a university computer (which I believe have i5s but not sure of the specifics) then it runs correctly with no errors. However, if I try to run it from my home PC (i7-3770) then it compiles correctly but generates a SIGILL error, I have looked at it using gdb but my assembly knowledge isn't the best. I've tried using flags such as `"-O2 -march=ivybridge"` and other things but no combination seems to work. I've reduced the code to the bare minimum but I'm still getting the same error.

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <graphics.h>


int main(void) {
    initialiseGraphics();
    loop( [&](){

    }
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
ifeq ($(origin ROOTDIR), undefined)
ROOTDIR=../..
endif
include $(ROOTDIR)/MakefileDefs.inc

# Build path
BUILD_DIR = build

TARGET = circlesAndRects
CPP_SOURCES = main.cpp

#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(CPP_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))
vpath %.cpp $(sort $(dir $(CPP_SOURCES)))

CFLAGS += -I$(INCDIR) -I$(JUCEINSTALL)/modules

LIBS =  $(LIBDIR)/libgraphics.a $(JUCELIB) $(LIBDIR)/libufcfgl-30-1.a

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(ECHO) compiling $<
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) Makefile
    $(ECHO) linking $<
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) $(LINUXLIBFALGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(ECHO) success

$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

#######################################
# install
#######################################
install:


#######################################
# clean up
#######################################
clean:
    -rm -fR .dep $(BUILD_DIR)

#######################################
# dependencies
#######################################
-include $(shell mkdir .dep 2>/dev/null) $(wildcard .dep/*)

.PHONY: clean all
```

gdb info:

```
Thread 1 "graphics1" received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction. 
0x000000000043a6ed in juce::File::isDirectory() const ()
```

Comment: You probably have the library compiled for a wrong CPU generation. Did you install it with your Ubuntu package manager or copied from another computer?

Comment: @n.m. copied from another computer, is there a way i could configure it to support both or would i manually have to change the library each time i switch computer? also how do i go about doing that?

Comment: In general you want to use your OS package manager to install everything, in this case `apt-get install libjuce-dev` or similar command should download and install what you need. Failing that, the next best thing is building from sources. Download and read build instructions somewhere in the root directory of the package.

Comment: @n.m. Still no luck; Using `apt-get install libjuce-dev` installed libjuce-dev and libjuce0, however I am still getting the same error. I've gone through the architecture of libjuce-dev and used `apt-get install` on all of the dependencies to make sure everything is installed and up to date, with no improvement. I'm a bit new to Ubuntu as a whole so the process to build from sources is still a bit unknown to me. Sorry to be such a pain.

Comment: You need to modify your makefile to use the installed library rather than your locally copied library. `LIBS` should probably contain `-ljuce` or similar instead of `$(JUCELIB)`. Don't know how JUCELIB or JUCEINSTALL are set. Is your makefile complete?

Comment: @n.m. My lecturer made a program to write the makefiles for us so I'm not particularly sure how or where the variables are set. That being said; changing `$(JUCELIB)` to `-ljuce` worked a charm and now it's all going correctly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Then you should complain to your lecturer about the error. It happens in the library *they* built.

Comment: You should use the projucer instead of using someone else's library build. It is meant to be built statically, not as a shared library.